# Issues with Devise routes - error in view pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes

I had an existing User model before I installed Devise so I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001318/is-it-possible-to-add-devise-if-user-model-already-exists).

I even generated the devise views.  But when I am at my localhost and type in localhost:3000/users/sign_in or any of the other routes available to me via devise, it doesn't work.

Also, my existing RESTful routes for users that I got from using

```
resources :users
```

are no longer available unless I have both:

```
devise_for :users
resources :users
```

but I thought I was supposed to delete the resources :users when I had the devise_for :users line in my routes file.

What is going on?  Does anyone have any idea?

EDIT

The issue is when I go to users/password, it tells me that there is no user with ID=password, but this route is available to me.

I also have issues with the users/sign_in and users/sign_out.  It redirects back to my root path for some reason.  Sometimes it works, other times it doesn't and I am not sure why.  The log looks like this:

```
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-09-16 19:05:43 -0400
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly doesn't work here?  Are you getting anything useful in the logs or elsewhere?  Also, have you setup your :users model to include the `devise :recoverable, :authenticateable, ...`, etc.?

You need both `devise_for` and `resources` defined in your config/routes.rb.  `devise_for` sets up routes that will go to the devise controllers, but does not handle anything else.  So you will still need normal resourceful routes for the user model to do add, update, delete, etc.

Comment: Hi, Just edited the question, basically my localhost:3000/users/password is not working.  It tells me "there is no user with ID=password".

Comment: @ming, make sure devise_for is defined in your routes.rb file before resources :users.  The routes.rb file is processed sequentially and will return the first route that matches.

Comment: thanks.  It turned out that the issue was not devise.  I realized the log says that mysql SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` IS NULL LIMIT 1.  Instead of pulling out the email xxx@abc.com, it pulls out email NULL.  Any idea why that is?